# Doing Simple Math in Tkinter Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to do a simple Python GUI Calculator. Everything is working fine right now. The Entry widget get my input however I have no idea how to add,minus,times etc and get the final output. For instance, I click on "1" + "2" = "3". when I clicked on "=", the answer will give me 3 in the entry widget. May I know how do I proceed?

Sample Code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def clear():
    txtDisplay.delete(0,END);
    return;

#Parent Window.
root = Tk();
root.title('Calculator ++ [1.7.2]');
root.geometry('350x450');

#Main entry.
num1 = StringVar();
txtDisplay = Entry(root, textvariable = num1, relief=RIDGE, bd = 10, width=33,    insertwidth = 1, font = 40);
txtDisplay.place(x=15, y=10);
txtDisplay.focus();


def update_entry(v):
    current_value = num1.get()
    num1.set(current_value + v)

#Buttons:
zeroButton = Button(root, text='0', width=20, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('0')).place(x=17,y=382);
oneButton = Button(root, text='1', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('1')).place(x=17, y=302);
twoButton = Button(root, text='2', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen',fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('2')).place(x=100, y=302);
threeButton = Button(root, text='3', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('3')).place(x=182, y=302);
fourButton = Button(root, text='4', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('4')).place(x=17, y=222);
fiveButton = Button(root, text='5', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('5')).place(x=100, y=222);
sixButton = Button(root, text='6', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('6')).place(x=182, y=222);
sevenButton = Button(root, text='7', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('7')).place(x=17, y=142);
eightButton = Button(root, text='8', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('8')).place(x=100, y=142);
ninthButton = Button(root, text='9', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('9')).place(x=182, y=142);

decimalButton = Button(root, text='.', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', command = lambda: update_entry('.')).place(x=182, y=382);
equalButton = Button(root, text='=', width=8, height=8, bg='Green', command = lambda: update_entry('=')).place(x=264, y=307);
plusButton = Button(root, text='+', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('+')).place(x=264, y=222);
minusButton = Button(root, text='-', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('-')).place(x=264, y=142);
multiplyButton = Button(root, text='x', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('x')).place(x=264, y=66);
divideButton = Button(root, text='÷', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('÷')).place(x=182, y=66);
clearButton = Button(root, text='Clear (CE)', width=20, height=3, command = clear, bg='Blue',fg="Pink").place(x=17, y=66);

#Locks the parent windows size.
root.maxsize(350,450);
root.minsize(350,450);

#Parent window's background color:
root.configure(background = 'black');
root.mainloop();
```

Comment: You only need to add something that somehow remembers the buttons that you pushed.

Comment: @usr2564301 . Yes I know that, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Going through [the official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) might help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do like that:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def clear():
    txtDisplay.delete(0,END);
    return;

#Parent Window.
root = Tk();
root.title('Calculator ++ [1.7.2]');
root.geometry('350x450');

#Main entry.
num1 = StringVar();
txtDisplay = Entry(root, textvariable = num1, relief=RIDGE, bd = 10, width=33,    insertwidth = 1, font = 40);
txtDisplay.place(x=15, y=10);
txtDisplay.focus();


def update_entry(v):
    current_value = num1.get()
    num1.set(current_value + v)

def equalOper():
    current_num = num1.get()
    support_oper = ['+', '-', 'x', '÷']
    result = ""
    for oper in support_oper:
        if oper in current_num:
            nums = current_num.split(oper)
            if oper == '+':
                result = str(float(nums[0]) + float(nums[1]))
            if oper == '-':
                result = str(float(nums[0]) - float(nums[1]))
            if oper == 'x':
                result = str(float(nums[0]) * float(nums[1]))
            if oper == '÷':
                result = str(float(nums[0]) / float(nums[1]))

    num1.set(result)

#Buttons:
zeroButton = Button(root, text='0', width=20, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('0')).place(x=17,y=382);
oneButton = Button(root, text='1', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('1')).place(x=17, y=302);
twoButton = Button(root, text='2', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen',fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('2')).place(x=100, y=302);
threeButton = Button(root, text='3', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('3')).place(x=182, y=302);
fourButton = Button(root, text='4', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('4')).place(x=17, y=222);
fiveButton = Button(root, text='5', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('5')).place(x=100, y=222);
sixButton = Button(root, text='6', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('6')).place(x=182, y=222);
sevenButton = Button(root, text='7', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('7')).place(x=17, y=142);
eightButton = Button(root, text='8', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('8')).place(x=100, y=142);
ninthButton = Button(root, text='9', width=8, height=3, bg='LightGreen', fg='brown', command = lambda: update_entry('9')).place(x=182, y=142);

decimalButton = Button(root, text='.', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', command = lambda: update_entry('.')).place(x=182, y=382);
equalButton = Button(root, text='=', width=8, height=8, bg='Green', command = lambda: equalOper()).place(x=264, y=307);
plusButton = Button(root, text='+', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('+')).place(x=264, y=222);
minusButton = Button(root, text='-', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('-')).place(x=264, y=142);
multiplyButton = Button(root, text='x', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('x')).place(x=264, y=66);
divideButton = Button(root, text='÷', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('÷')).place(x=182, y=66);
clearButton = Button(root, text='Clear (CE)', width=20, height=3, command = clear, bg='Blue',fg="Pink").place(x=17, y=66);



#Locks the parent windows size.
root.maxsize(350,450);
root.minsize(350,450);

#Parent window's background color:
root.configure(background = 'black');
root.mainloop();
```

The only question is the data accuracy.